# Why am I getting Time limit exceeded for my this code?

Tags: java

Why am i getting Time limit exceeded for ans for my this code?
I tried this question on CodeChef.My logic is correct but my answer is showing time limit exceeded  , i don't know why ?

http://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFRP

```
package test;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test 
{


public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    int TESTCASES;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
    TESTCASES=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int b=2*TESTCASES,i=0,m,l;
    int a;
    String[] lines=new String[b];
    int[] N=new int[TESTCASES];
    int[][] Ai =new int[TESTCASES][100001];  
    int[] min=new int[TESTCASES];
    int flag=0,minusonecase=-1;
    int[] sum=new int[TESTCASES]
```

;

```
    for(a=0;a<b;a++)
    { 
        lines[a]=br.readLine();
        if(a%2==0)
        {
            N[a/2]=Integer.parseInt(lines[a]);
        }
        if(a%2!=0)
        {
            StringTokenizer stz=new StringTokenizer(lines[a]);
            for(l=0;l<100001;l++)
            {
            if(stz.countTokens()!=0) 
            {
                    Ai[((a-1)/2)][l]=Integer.parseInt(stz.nextToken());  
            }
         else{



             break;
         }




        }

    }

    }       

    for(a=0;a<TESTCASES;a++)
    {
        min[a]=Ai[a][0];

        for(l=0;l<N[a];l++)
          {
                    if(min[a]>Ai[a][l])
                    {
                        min[a]=Ai[a][l];

                    }
                sum[a]=sum[a]+Ai[a][l];

        }
        sum[a]=sum[a]+2-min[a];
    }

       for(a=0;a<TESTCASES;a++)
             {
                 for(l=0;l<N[a];l++)
                 {
                     if(Ai[a][l]==1)
                     {  
                        System.out.println(minusonecase);
                        flag=1;
                        break;

                     }

                 }
                 if(flag==1)
                 {
                     flag=0;
                     continue;
                 }
                 System.out.println(sum[a]);
             }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the question correctly -

> Rupsa recently started to intern under Chef. He gave her N type of ingredients of varying quantity A1, A2, ..., AN respectively to store it. But as she is lazy to arrange them she puts them all in a storage box.
>
> Chef comes up with a new recipe and decides to prepare it. He asks Rupsa to get two units of each type ingredient for the dish. But when she went to retrieve the ingredients, she realizes that she can only pick one item at a time from the box and can know its type only after she has picked it out. The picked item is not put back in the bag.
>
> She, being lazy, wants to know the maximum number of times she would need to pick items from the box in the worst case so that it is guaranteed that she gets at least two units of each type of ingredient. If it is impossible to pick items in such a way, print -1.

You are not handling the case , where one of the ingredients has less than 2 unit, in which case you should be printing -1.

Comment: But i am considering it

Comment: Now if you are getting time limit exceeded that would be because you are going through the testcase like multiple times , and going through N multiple times. A better solution would be to do all , inlcuding printing and maybe including reading the input in a single loop, try that.